# Optimize postgress query for large set of data

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

A Postgress database table exists with around 4 million rows of product information. Available columns are product id, `SKU`, product barcodes (`array field`) & product description, etc. Here, users will upload `CSV` files of product data. Each product may contain multiple barcodes. The data will be updated based on existing product barcodes from DB. If the barcode already exists, the product row from `CSV` file will be skipped, or the product will not be added from `CSV`. Otherwise, a new row will be added with product information and a task will be created for manual validation of the product that is inserted. These validation process is done by the admin manually. So I have to check every row before inserting data into the table and the query time is very high as there is a large number of data. The barcode column is indexed already.

The query I used to check if barcode exists:

```
SELECT * FROM retail_retailinventory WHERE ARRAY['*****'] <@ barcodes
```

However, if any match is not found I have to trigger 5 insertions to different models like Inventory, PosModel, and Task model. All are dependent. So this operation has to be triggered synchronously. I tried to use bulk_create, but can not be succeeded yet as I have to maintain the foreign key relationship among the models. This insertion process is filling most of the memory and timeout occurs.

Is there any way to optimize the process? Or any scope to apply Machine Learning in this case? My concern is if I apply ML, the machine needs to be trained every-time a new row is inserted into the database and it would not be a good solution.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the memory of the process running this isn't a problem, you could do the following:

```
from itertools import chain
existing_barcodes = set(chain.from_iterable(RetailInventory.objects.all().values_list('barcodes', flat=True)))

while csv_processing:
    line = # next csv line
    if line['barcode'] in existing_barcodes:
        continue
```

Ideally you'd be able to limit the initial fetch to only the relevant products. So maybe iterate over the CSV twice? The first to fetch the product and barcodes so you can see which are actually new in single query, then the second to process them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the index:

```
create index on retail_retailinventory using GIN (barcodes)
```

Then rewrite the WHERE clause to be:

```
WHERE ARRAY['*****'] <@ barcodes
```

Comment: Thank you @jjanes. I indexed the column and gain some performance. However, I faced another issue. I edited the question. Have a look if you have time. Thanks for the answer.